# jquery syntax to call script on the server using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

We are doing jquery ajax post call to the server using jquery form plug-in(http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started). Once we got the response.

We need to parse this and make one more ajax call on the server. Please let me know the syntax to call this using jquery.

```
$('#MyForm').ajaxForm({
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("My form submit successful.The response is >>" + data);
    // Process this response and call another script on  the server.
  }
});
```

Comment: its correct. what is the current issue you are currently facing !

Comment: what does `data` looks like (JSON, HTML, blob...) ? What do you need from the second ajax call, what is its type (POST, GET)?

Comment: Data is a json and the second ajax also returns a json. This is GET call.

Answer (score 1):

To issue an ajax request from within a callback function looks like the following: nothing special, nothing unusual.

```
$('#MyForm').ajaxForm({
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("My form submit successful.The response is >>" + data);
    // Process this response and call another script on  the server.
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET", /*string "GET" or "POST"*/
       data: {}, /* query string or object with properties to pass to the server */
       url: "url.com", /* url of the next script */
       success: function () {/* success callback code */},
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another ajax call in success function like this:

```
$('#MyForm').ajaxForm({
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("My form submit successful.The response is >>" + data);
    // Process this response and call another script on  the server.

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://yourURL',
      data: {
        var: 'val',
        ..
      },
      type: 'POST', //GET
      datatype: 'text', //XML,JSON
      success: function(result) {
        //result data handling
      }
      error: functionn() {
        //error handling
      }
    });
  }
});
```